# Comparing functions that have logs in exponents

Tags: logarithms

I'm not that familiar with logs in general so not sure how to handle when say comparing two functions to see which one would grow slower / faster

$$n^{\log\log n}$$

to this...

$$(\log n)^{\log n}$$

Anyone able to help clarify?  Just not sure what I should be doing when a log is in the exponent.  I've only dealt with functions that have a base that is the same as the base of the function.  For example...

$$2^{\log_2 9} = 9$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "comparing"? "what I should be doing when a log is in the exponent" is also a tad unspecific - why should you do anything? Could you perhaps give an example of your problem(s)?

Comment: It's just comparing different functions to see which grow faster.  Similar to this...

math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382947/how-to-recognise-intuitively-which-functions-grow-faster-asymptotically?rq=1

Where the person has similar functions but the response leaves it as (how?) for an explanation.  found it after I posted...trying to make sense of it

Comment: Okay. Have you tried using the answer to the question you linked to (i.e. taking the limit)? Also, there is no $n$ in your second equation.. do you mean $\log n^{\log n}$?

Comment: Fixed the ns - we didn't go over limits so I figured there is no need.

Comment: @pad11 What do you mean by *we didn't go over limits?*  How do you expect to do this without limits?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear (sorry I didn't ask this in the first go): You mean $(\log n)^{\log n}$, right?

Comment: Are we to assume $\log$ means base $e$ or base $10$.  The principal is the same either way.

Comment: In class, limits was not discussed at all.  I have no idea how to handle it with limits.  If that is the way to handle it, I'll see what I can read about it

Comment: ... and what exactly are you supposed to be comparing and noticing about them.  One is an expression.  The other is another expression.  What are we supposed to *do* with them?  Express one in terms of the other?

Comment: @Lovsovs: i fixed it

Comment: @fleablood:  I revised it but it's comparing growth

Comment: typically how I've handled other examples is to take the logs on both sides or use algebra to cancel out stuff

Comment: Is $\log n^{\log n}$ supposed to be $(\log n)^{\log n}$ or $\log(n^{\log n})$.

Comment: @fleablood - I've revised it but it's the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare which of the functions $f(n)=n^{\log  \log n}$ and $g(n)=(\log n)^{\log n}$ grows faster. To determine this, let's look at their ratio (where $\log$ is assumed to be the natural logarithm and $t=\log n$)
$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{n^{\log \log n}}{(\log n)^{\log n}}=\frac{(e^t)^{\log t}}{t^t}=\frac{e^{t \log t}}{e^{t \log t}}=1,$$

and hence they grow at the same rate!

To show $t^t=e^{t \log t}$, let's solve $$t^t=e^{kt}=(e^k)^t \implies t=e^k \implies k=\log t.$$

Comment: ok thank you.  I think I got it.  Do you mind me asking how you get e^t from n?

Comment: is it that you're using log base e as well?  so that e^(log_e n) just means n?

Comment: @pad11 Yes indeed.

Comment: ok thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

$n^{\log \log n} =(e^{\log n})^{\log \log n}=(e^{\log \log n})^{\log n} = (\log n)^{\log n} $

so they are the same thing.

Comment: I feel like a fool!  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Ok mind if I ask what property you're using?  I'm not sure why you can switch out n for e^log n  and then back to log n at the end.  Sorry, I haven't touch this sort of stuff in a while and it was brushed over quickly in class with very basic examples (no logs as exponents)

Comment: @pad11 See last couple of lines in my answer to see why it can be done.

Comment: $(a^x)^y = a^{x*y} = (a^y)^x$ so  $n^{\log(gump)} = (e^{\log n})^{\log(gump)} = e^{\log n * \log(gump)} = (e^{\log(gump)})^{\log n} = gump^{\log(n)}$.  So that's a neat little result I've never noticed: $a^{\log b} = b^{\log a}$ because $a^{\log b} = e^{\log a*\log b} = b^{\log a}$.  Maybe I did learn that in high school and since have forgotten it the it is *VERY* neat, I think.  So $n^{\log (\log n)} = (\log n)^{\log n}$.

Comment: Basic definition:  $a = b^{\log_b a} ; a = \log_b b^a= a\log_b b = a$.  So if you need to compare $b^x ?  a^y$ so can do $b^x = e^{x\log b}; a^y = e^{y\log a}$ and compare $x\log b$ vs $y\log a$ if its any easier.  Likes comparing $a$ vs $ \log x$ we can do $a = \log e^{\log a}$ and compare $\log a$ vs. $x$ if it's any easier.

Comment: ok thanks @fleablood!